# How to display a color palette in the web page using cakephp?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, color-picker

I need help in displaying a colour palette in my application. I am using CakePHP and JQuery for implementing mu application. For my themes module I need a colour picker or colour palette. Is there any plugin to download and use or is there any helpers available? Can someone guide me.

**EDIT**

Is there any other simpler plugin, that just displays the color palette alone and not with the hues,getting rgb values separately and all..
Just the color boxes,n pick one from it.

I found one plugin 
 [at this site](http://www.web2media.net/laktek/2008/10/27/really-simple-color-picker-in-jquery/) . It was like what I wanted. But it displays the colours,only on selecting that color input box. I want the colors to be displayed initially itself.Any help?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [ColorPicker jQuery plugin](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/).

Comment: Is there any other simpler plugin, that just displays the color palette alone and not with the hues,getting rgb values separately and all..
Just the color boxes,n pick one from it.

I found one plugin 
 <a href="http://www.web2media.net/laktek/2008/10/27/really-simple-color-picker-in-jquery/">at this site </a>. It was like what I wanted. But it displays the colours,only on selecting that color input box. I want the colors to be displayed initially itself.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like the [Farbtastic picker](http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic) a lot.
There's a long list of pickers [here](http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/ColorPicker).